# Is xinitrc executed when logging in?

Tags: xorg, x11, login

I have a `~/.xinitrc` with the following content

```
xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xdefaults
```

this `xinitrc` is basically useless because it's not loaded when the user logs in, I don't think that I'm doing something wrong because the same command works on the `bash`, my question is: does `xinitrc` recognize the environment variables?

Comment: Are you using something like `startx` to start X? I don't think your `.xinitrc` will be read if you are using a login manager.

Comment: @phunehehe I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Comment: Then you are using Ubuntu's default login manager (`lightdm`). You may want to [add a start-up application](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321/1599) instead.

Comment: I am just solved alike problem: I am tried to set Awesom as my window manager, and it's Wiki recommended to use `.xinitrc`. In fact it is do not work for me, but I occasionally found that the `.xsessionrc` instead works.

Answer (score 5):

`.xinitrc` is exectued when you explicitly run `xinit` (`startx` ultimately calls `xinit`)to start an X-server. Mostly this doesn't happen as current Linuxes use desktop managers, which diretly start a X-Server and then run `/etc/X11/Xsession <desktopenvironment>`, where `<desktopenvironment>` is the value of any line `Exec=` from a file in `/usr/share/xsessions`, for instance

```
Exec=startxfce4
```

if you selected XFCE as sessiontype.

On at least Debian based systems the scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` are sourced (!) in order. Mostly all these scripts set stuff up and/or modify a variable `STARTUP` which is eventually used in the line

```
exec $STARTUP
```

So technically you could write a `/usr/share/xsession/xinitrc.desktop` file which lets you select a session which will run `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: Doesn't the display manager need X started as well? So why doesn't the display manager itself need `~/.xinitrc` prior to launching?

Comment: Yes, display managers require an Xserver. Starting X directly, i.e., running the `Xorg` binary does not care for `~/.xinitrc`. This is what usually happens today. The DM itself does as it pleases and requires "only" a running Xserver

Comment: I found out that DMs have their own configuration that can run commands before the DM launches.

Answer (score 5):

`~/.xinitrc` is only read if you start X11 with `startx` (or anything that calls `xinit`). If you log in in graphics mode, the display manager chooses a session to start. Each session manager or desktop environment has its own startup script(s), if any.

Most systems automatically load resources from `~/.Xresources` as part of the default X11 startup scripts. Try renaming your resources file to `~/.Xresources`.